# jmockit, openJDK and UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: freebsd, java, jmockit

When trying to run test with JMockit on OpenJDK 6, I'm facing the error:

```
[junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:353)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1052)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:906)
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native library for Attach API not available in this JRE
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:81)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:54)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:21)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfNeeded(Startup.java:200)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfPossible(Startup.java:215)
[junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.<clinit>(TestResult.java:19)
[junit]     ... 3 more
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.isLinuxThreads()Z
[junit]     at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.isLinuxThreads(Native Method)
[junit]     at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<clinit>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:364)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:71)
[junit]     ... 8 more
```

I looked inside folder /usr/local/openjdk6/jre/lib/amd64/ and found **libattach.so** there

However adding **-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/openjdk6/jre/lib/amd64** didn't solve the problem. What else I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `<jdk6home>/lib/tools.jar` to the classpath, *before* jmockit.jar. If that doesn't solve the problem, passing `-javaagent:jmockit.jar` as a JVM initialization parameter definitely should.

Answer (score 1):

What I noticed in my case I was pointing to JRE6 instead of JDK6. As soon as I point my JAVA_HOME to jdk6 its fixed the problem